# 'No compatible servers were found' error message

Tags: mysql, database

When I install the MySql Workbench, it show this message:

> No compatible servers were found.

You'll need to cancel this wizard and install one.

But I believe it is install together. What is the error?

Answer (score 4):

Try to install latest version of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages. This solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this happens because you had not installed the requirements manually mentioned in the previous steps. I recommend that you uninstall and install it back again. After that, you have to click on these items in order to try to resolve them manually. It performs the installation of Visual C +++ 2019.